# How to automatically mount a file containing an encrypted file system, when a user login?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nautilus, luks

The file can be mounted manually via 'cryptsetup luksOpen' and 'mount /dev/mapper' but I would like it to be mounted automatically while logging in and by showing a GUI dialog for the passphrase just like gnome/nautilus/ubuntu (?) is doing when an encrypted mass storage USB device is connected.

The (loopback) file containing the encrypted file system, is stored in a user's non-encrypted home directory.

Answer (score 1):

if you have cryptsetup, configure your `/etc/crypttab`:

```
#<target name><source device><key file><options>
dm-2    UUID=XXXX  arg  luks,keyscript=/root/script.sh,noearly
```

`cryptsetup` will execute `/root/script.sh arg` and all it gives on output takes as passphrase to unlock devices.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome has a 'startup applications' program. If you are using Unity you should just be able to access it with `<Super> start <ENTER>`. From here enter the command that makes the prompt pop up. Unfortunately I wasn't quite sure what you are referring to, so I can't tell you how to do that. Another method is contained on the ubuntu wiki for [FolderEncryption](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption#Automatically_Mounting_on_Startup)

Comment: The GUI dialog looks like this: [link](http://www.roysindre.no/files/2008/11/screenshot-unlock-encrypted-data.png)
It is automatically displayed when a LUKS encrypted USB mass storage device is connected, but I don't know how. Based on some googling I suspect that Nautilus is involved somehow.